# How to build dictionary using {quanteda} with various different adjectives connected to one single noun?

Tags: r, dictionary, quanteda

Say I have text data like this example text below which I need to analyze using a self-built dictionary.

> Good X. Perfect X. Magnificent X. Extraordinary X. Bad X. Abysmal X. Very poor X.

Based on that, I want to build a dictionary using {quanteda} using this code structure:

```
dict <- quanteda::dictionary(list(.))
```

Is there a way how I could specify which adjectives I'm looking for without haveing to type X for each adjective of interest?

```
# Example of what I want to avoid:
dict <- quanteda::dictionary(list(
  list_1 = c("good X", "perfect X",...)
))
```

So ideally, I would need something like "good/perfect/... X", but I know that it won't work like this. Is there a solution?

Comment: Why don't you use a POS tagger and dependency parser (e.g. with spacyr or udpipe), it shows you the adjectives with the pos tagger and the dependency parser indicates which words are linked to the adjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can list the precursor adjectives as a regular expression, using the "or" operator `|`, followed by `X`.

Here, I used `exclusive = FALSE` just to show which tokens had been replaced by the key and which not.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

dict <- dictionary(list(mykey = "^(good|perfect|magnificient)$ X"))

tokens("I had a good X at the magnificient X hotel.") %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = dict, valuetype = "regex", exclusive = FALSE)
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "I"     "had"   "a"     "MYKEY" "at"    "the"   "MYKEY" "hotel" "."
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to follow-up: what do I need `^` and `$` for? I tried without those and it worked just fine.

Comment: You need it to indicate the start or end of a token, otherwise you will also match "imperfect" or "goods" for instance.